# A* implementation for solving 8puzzle - java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

I'm currently coding an implementation of the A* algorithm in order to solve 8puzzle. I've been progressing quite a lot but my algorithm seems to be stucked in an infinite process and I really don't see where I made mistakes.

Here is my code :

Board.java :

```
public class Board {

    private int currentState[][] = new int[3][3];
    private int nbMoves; // variable for the cost of the current board
    private int manhattanDistance;
    private int f = manhattanDistance + nbMoves;

    public Board() {}

    public Board(int b1[][]) {
        this.currentState = b1;
    }

    public int getValue(int x, int y) {
        return currentState[x][y];
    }

    public void setValue(int n, int x, int y) {
        currentState[x][y] = n;
    }

    public int getNbMoves() {
        return nbMoves;
    }

    public void setNbMoves(int n) {
        nbMoves = n;
    }

    // Function to get the x coordinate of the specified value n
    public int getX(int n) {
        int posX = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (currentState[i][j] == n) {
                    posX = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return posX;
    }

    // Function to get the y coordinate of the specified value n
    public int getY(int n) {
        int posY = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (currentState[i][j] == n) {
                    posY = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return posY;
    }

    // Function to get and stock the Coordinate of the desired value in a 1D array coord
    // We will use it to get the coordinates of the 0 tile.
    public void getCoordinate(int coord[], int n) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (currentState[i][j] == n) {
                    coord[0] = i;
                    coord[1] = j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to get the current state of the board
    public void getCurrentState(int state[][]) {
        state = this.currentState;
    }

    // Function to test if 2 boards are the same
    public boolean equals(int b[][]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (this.currentState[i][j] != b[i][j]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void setManhattanDistance() {
        int md = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {

                int value = currentState[x][y]; // Contain the value of the tile

                // Then we calculate the Manhattan Distance for each tile,
                // except for the 0 tile.
                if (value != 0) { 
                    int expected_X = (value - 1) / 3; // expected vertical coordinate
                    int expected_Y = (value - 1) % 3; // expected horizontal coordinate
                    int true_x = x - expected_X;
                    int true_y = y - expected_Y;

                    md += Math.abs(true_x) + Math.abs(true_y);
                }
            }
        }
        manhattanDistance = md;
    }

    // Function to set the f() value
    public int getF() {
        return f;
    }

    // Function for printing the current state of board
    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
                System.out.print(currentState[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

BFSearch.java :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class BFSearch {

    private ArrayList<Board> closedlist = new ArrayList<Board>();
    private ArrayList<Board> openlist = new ArrayList<Board>();
    private ArrayList<Board> getChildren = new ArrayList<Board>();

    private Board currentState,goalState = new Board();


    public BFSearch(int start[][], int goal[][]) {
        currentState = new Board(start);
        goalState = new Board(goal);
    }


    // Function to get every children possible for the current state of the board
    // A board can have a maximum of 4 children (1 for every direction)
    public ArrayList<Board> children(Board currentState) {
        Board newState = new Board();
        ArrayList<Board> children = new ArrayList<Board>();
        Pos p = new Pos();

        newState = p.Up(currentState);

        // If the move is possible, then we increment by 1 the number of moves (to calculate f() value)
        // we calculate it's manhattan distance,
        // and we add it to the list of children
        if (newState != null) {
            newState.setNbMoves(currentState.getNbMoves() + 1);
            newState.setManhattanDistance();
            children.add(newState);
        }

        newState = p.Down(currentState);

        // If the move is possible, then we increment by 1 the number of moves (to calculate f() value)
        // we calculate it's manhattan distance,
        // and we add it to the list of children
        if (newState != null) {
            newState.setNbMoves(currentState.getNbMoves() + 1);
            newState.setManhattanDistance();
            children.add(newState);
        }

        newState = p.Left(currentState);

        // If the move is possible, then we increment by 1 the number of moves (to calculate f() value)
        // we calculate it's manhattan distance,
        // and we add it to the list of children
        if (newState != null) {
            newState.setNbMoves(currentState.getNbMoves() + 1);
            newState.setManhattanDistance();
            children.add(newState);
        }

        newState = p.Right(currentState);

        // If the move is possible, then we increment by 1 the number of moves (to calculate f() value)
        // we calculate it's manhattan distance,
        // and we add it to the list of children
        if (newState != null) {
            newState.setNbMoves(currentState.getNbMoves() + 1);
            newState.setManhattanDistance();
            children.add(newState);
        }

        return children;
    }


    public void solve() {
        boolean solved = false;

        int movecount = 0;

        currentState.setNbMoves(0);

        // We add the currentState of the board to the open list
        openlist.add(currentState);

        // While we don't have a solution
        while (!solved) {
            currentState = openlist.get(0);

            // If we arrived at the goal state then we print it and stop the program
            if (currentState.equals(goalState)) {
                currentState.print();
                solved = true;
            }

            // We get the list of possible children
            getChildren = children(currentState);

            // We move the First board of the open list to the closed list
            closedlist.add(currentState);
            openlist.remove(0);

            // Need to sort the children depending on their f() value
            // I declared an anonymous comparator for that.
            Collections.sort(getChildren, new Comparator<Board>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Board b1, Board b2) {
                    Integer f1 = b1.getF();
                    Integer f2 = b2.getF();
                    return f1.compareTo(f2);
                }
            });

            // Then, we add the children to the open list
            for (Board b : getChildren) {
                openlist.add(b);
            }

            movecount++;
        }

        // We print every step of the solution
        for (Board bd : closedlist) {
            bd.print();
        }

        // We print the number of move required
        System.out.println("Number of move required : " + movecount);
    }
}
```

Then, my main to execute the program, EightPuzzle.java :

```
public class EightPuzzle {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      int startState[][] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,0}};
      int goalState[][] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,0}};

      BFSearch bfs = new BFSearch(startState, goalState);

      System.out.println("Researching the solution...");
      bfs.solve();
  }
}
```

I have another classes (Pos.java) that mostly do the movements for the tiles (like moving up, swaping, etc...) but I don't think the problem comes from that one.

When I execute my program, there is only the "Researching the solution..." printing then nothing even if I wait a lot of time. Even when the start state and the goal state are the same... (as you see in the main program)

If you would have any ideas, thank you a lot !

Comment: Have you try debugging? you can check where is the infinite loop problem

Comment: This is the perfect moment to start your debugger and find out where your problem resides.

Comment: Oh, also your problem is that you call `equals` on an `int[][]` which is never going to return true for you. Use `Arrays.deepEquals`. Next time debug it though, that would be amazingly easy to find ("oh when start and goal are the same it still does not go in that if... wonder why. let's google that...")

Comment: I've never tried debugging, I'm quite new to java. I guess I should try @Rcordoval

Comment: @Ben Thank you ! Didn't know about `Arrays.deepEquals` Even if I changed it, it's still not working though, but I will look at the debugger !

Comment: To make the code [mcve] you need to add `Pos` and remove what is not essential.

Comment: I think you also want to add `break;`  after `solved = true;`